# Javascript age calculation to be outputted to a string, to HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a program to calculate my exact age, to the day, to be outputted to a string, to be displayed on my website. My code so far is the following:

```js
// establishing today's date
let currentTime = new Date();
let month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
let day = currentTime.getDate();
let year = currentTime.getFullYear();

// my birthdate
const birthMonth = 7;
const birthDay = 24;
const birthYear = 2004;

// comparing the two dates
let monthDifference = Math.abs(month - birthMonth);
let dayDifference = Math.abs(day - birthDay);
let yearDifference = Math.abs(year - birthYear);

// save and return the difference in a readable format
let comparison = `${yearDifference} year, \
        ${monthDifference} month, ${dayDifference} day`;
document.getElementById("birthday paragraph").innerText = `I \
        am a ${comparison} old programmer from Concord, Ohio.`;
```

```html
<div id="birthday paragraph"></div>
```

However, as you can see on [crossflame22.github.io](https://crossflame22.github.io) (if I haven't already fixed it), it displays the incorrect day. Today, it's showing 1 month, 5 days. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: The date difference (17 year, 1 month, 5 day) appears to display fine in the code snippet in your question.

Comment: [From the MDN page for `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): _`id's` value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the `class` attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value."_  You're playing with fire, friend-- get that space out of there.

Comment: Yep, showing correctly both with this code and in your question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your code only 'works' on months of the year later than the base month, and days of the month after the base day.  Otherwise, applying 'abs' to the negative result is wrong: it should be 12 + (negative month) and then reduce years by 1.  It's even more complex for the days.  On August 19, 2021 it should be 17 years 0 months 26 days.  17y 1m 5d is correct for August 29, 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Use a library (like `date-fns`) instead of trying to use simple differences. There is almost never a good reason to try to do time difference calculations yourself across days, as you will undoubtedly do it wrong. If you adamantly want to do this, you need to handle a lot of edge cases.

Long answer: Your current logic doesn't account for leap years (which add days to your life), but it also assumes that being in and adjacent month credits you with a whole month. As an example, say you were born on July 31, 2021. Your code would imply you are immediately 1 month old on Aug 1, 2021 (even though clearly you are only 1 day old). You could probably do something like what you're doing if months were the same length (they aren't) and years were the same length (they aren't). Even days can have different lengths (see leap seconds), which can impact longer term calculations. Hence why you should look into a library designed to handled these edge cases for you.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by rfestag is good advice.

However, let's take a look at the problem and perhaps offer a simple approach.

As rfestag pointed out, date computations are very complex due to leap years, months being different lengths, and so on.

Forget years for a minute, and consider what it means to say "X months old"?
A baby born on Jan 1 is 3 months old on March 31 (90 days).
A baby born on July 1 is 3 months old on Sept 30 (92 days).
Those two "3 month old" babies are not the exact same age!

So try this approach:
Compute the difference between the two days, then convert that to approximate (years, months, days).

```
// get your inputs however you like, I'll just hard code them

const today = new Date();
const baseday = new Date("July 24, 2004");

let difference = today - baseday;
difference /= 24*3600*1000; // convert milliseconds to days

let yeardiff = Math.floor(difference/(365.25)); // whole number of average years
let monthdiff = (difference - yeardiff*365.25); // last partial year

let averagemonth = 365.25/12;  // length of average month
let months = Math.floor(monthdiff/averagemonth);

let daysleft = Math.floor(monthdiff - months * averagemonth);
console.log(yeardiff + " years, " + months + " months, " + daysleft + " days");
```

For some days of the year (around the start of months mostly), it may be off in the days, but for general purposes it should be good enough.